# 2007 Nissan Maxima Windows and Sunroof are Unresponsive

Tags: electrical

All the windows will not go up or down including the sunroof. Everything else is working. The fuse under the hood looks ok. There no sign of it being bad. Can it still be the fuse and if not what else can it be? Should I replace the fuse any way?

The vehicle is a 2007 Nissan Maxima.

Answer (score 2):

To be sure on the fuse either replace it or better still, test it with a multimeter.  Test it for conductivity.

The fuse may look visibly ok but still be broken.

The multimeter is going to be needed to test past the fuse also as you will need to find where the break in the circuit is.